# How to get correct ssbo array index when using multiDrawArraysIndirect?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my shader I have an ssbo containing an array of structs.

```
layout(std430, binding = 14) readonly buffer Block {
    Uniform uniform[];
};
```

Now I want to use glDrawArraysIndirect and I need to pass the index for the ssbo with each draw command.

I am using opengl version 4.5 and extension ARB_shader_draw parameters is not supported.

The additional problems are that I am using a triple buffer, so I need to add the offset to the current part of the buffer to the index and the draw commands will not necessarily be in the same order as the structs in the buffer are.

If there is no way to get around draw commands being in a different order I could reorder them, but I would avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was an easy way to get around ARB_shader_draw_parameters's functionality... the functionality wouldn't need to exist.

The closest approximation to ARB_shader_draw_parameters is to use the base instance index in the draw indirect command. Each draw you generate would assign itself a base instance, and that index represents the index used to index into the array.

Of course, ARB_shader_draw_parameters also provides access to the `gl_BaseInstanceARB` value, which is the base instance field from the draw command. It provides this because `gl_InstanceID` *is not affected* by the base instance. Only the value fetched from [vertex shader instanced arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Instanced_Array) is affected by the base instance.

So in order to use the base instance, you have to have an instance array which is just a linearly increasing series of integers. That value would be the base instance index you need.

And since you're not able to use `gl_DrawIDARB`, such a base instance value would not be guaranteed to [dynamically uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Dynamically_Uniform_Expression). So you cannot use the index, or any expressions derived from it, to do the following, among other things:

- Index into an array of samplers or other opaque types.
- Index into an array of interface blocks (not arrays *within* a block. An array of blocks themselves)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. But I still have the question how the triple buffer offset is usually solved. Just pass the offset through a glUniform1ui and add it to my base instance value or is there a better way?